Go. No packages found for open file C:\Users\user\Documents\go-discord-rpc\main.go. This file is ignored by your gopls build
Проект требует использование python2.7, с его поддержкой нет нужной библиотеки. Было принято решение использовать CGO.
При добавлении пакета C для компиляции модуля в .so файл, возникает ошибка, перестает видеть пакет main. Если переставлять место импорта пакета C, то никакого результата это не дает.
package main

import "C"

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {}

// export discord_rpc
func discord_rpc(details, state, largeImage, smallImage, LargeText, smallText string) {
    client, err := New("938480952844386364")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = client.SetActivity(Activity{
        Details: details,
        State:   state,
        Timestamps: &Timestamps{
            Start: time.Now().Add(-time.Minute * 5),
            // End:   time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 5),
        },
        Assets: &Assets{
            LargeImage: largeImage,
            LargeText:  LargeText,
            SmallText:  smallText,
            SmallImage: smallImage,
        },
        // Buttons: []dButton{
        //  {
        //      Label: "Google",
        //      URL:   "https://youtube.com",
        //  },
        //  {
        //      Label: "Discord",
        //      URL:   "https://discord.com",
        //  },
        // },

    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 30)
}


Директива import "C" должна быть на отдельной строке перед остальными импортами.

@PakUula ошибка остается той же
